# Swagger UI not displaying JSON files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to document an API with Swagger (in `Rails` with gem `swagger-docs`). I have some basic documentation complete. Ran `sudo SD_LOG_LEVEL=1 rake swagger:docs RAILS_ENV=production` without any errors.

My problem is the Swagger UI doesn't show my all documentation when navigating to the JSON. I can view individual files/controllers (ie. `users.json`), but when I access `api-docs.json`, I can see the copyright and company information, etc. but none of my APIs.

Each controller has its documentation written to `{root}/public/apis/v1/*.json`.

Screenshots:

[image: api-docs.json shows api description only]
[image: example json file that exists and that I should see]

Answer (score 1):

Can u post URL in swagger docs like base path and version method and docs/index.html URL line there might be some mismatch with your base path mentioned in swagger docs and generated swagger files

Comment: base_path: `/`; Swagger explore URL: `http://192.168.33.7:31000/api/v1/api-docs.json`; API controller location in project: `web/app/controllers`

Comment: Or if u have common config yml file which can be used over entire app u can mention that yml URL in index.html and base path